# Bullmq retry completed jobs manually

Tags: node.js, redis, webhooks, bullmq, bull

I'm using bullmq to send webhooks events. Jobs are scheduled and an automatic retry is in place. Let's say I want to re-execute some tasks which already successfully completed and I have the ids of the elements in the queue I want to reschedule, is it possible to set those task as "to repeat" manually by moving them in the waiting queue somehow with redis?